# Как сделать такую ленту с цикличным текстом?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть дизайн для верстки, и на нем есть такой элемент:

[image: Текст "LOREM IPSUM LOREM IPSUMLOREM IPSUM" с двумя флагами японии по боковым сторонам]

Т.е. это вот такой `<div>` на 100% ширины экрана и внутри этого div-а текст с картинками (два маленьких флага  Японии), и они должны вот так повторяться, вместе с картинками . Пробовал гуглить, но не знаю по каким ключевым словам это можно найти :3

Comment: она должна быть анимированной (движущейся) или не?

Comment: @darinkapoznyak нет

Answer (score -2):

```css
body {
   display: flex;
   min-height: 100vh;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 0;
}
div {
   margin: auto;
   background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='320px' height='30px' version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Ctext x='10' y='20' style='font-family: sans-serif; fill: %233A1514; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: .8rem; font-weight: 600'%3E  lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum %3C/text%3E%3C/svg%3E");
   background-position: center;
   width: 110vw;
   height: 30px;
   transform: rotate(1deg);
   border: 1px solid #3a1514;
   border-left: none;
   border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: у меня иконка еще есть помимо флага японии да и флаг не тот, может есть какая то либа?

Comment: @midnightelf18 я вам показал принцип, как решить ваш вопрос. Дальше сами.